# ui5 SplitContainer not passing event data to onBeforeShow in child element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sapui5

I'm writing an OpenUI5 application, utilising a TileContainer Launchpad, SplitContainer, Master and Detail pages. The SplitContainer needs to service three different models, each with the same structure (but different data). This means that the master and detail are reused for each model, but I have to tell the master which model it's using. Sequence goes:

Launchpad tiles displayed:

```
data = model.getData(); // from model, includes an attribute 'model'
                        // to tell the subsequent page which model to use
if (data && data.Menu) {
  for (m = 0; m < data.Menu.length; m++) {
    menu = data.Menu[m];
    tc.addTile(new sap.m.StandardTile({
      icon: menu.icon,
      title: menu.title,
      info: menu.title,
      press: navFn(menu.model) // here, the model to use is passed in the function params
    }));
  }
}
```

User clicks tile with specific parameters in the 'press' event to indicate which model to use. Navigation function raises the event with the data payload and App controller handles navigation. This works.

```
this.bus.publish("nav", "to", {
  id: "my.Main",
  data: {
      model: model // received from function parameters
  }
});
```

Main view (containing a SplitContainer) is called and receives the event **with the supplied event data** in onBeforeShow; and in function onBeforeShow in Main view, we call the Master view with function toMaster on the SplitContainer, supplying the same event data (specifying the model to use)

```
onBeforeShow: function(event) { //event contains data.model (verified in debugging)
  var container = sap.ui.getCore().byId("my.Main.container");
  container.toMaster("my.Master", "show", { model: event.data.model }); //oData parameter
}
```

Master view is called but in method `onBeforeShow`, event data object **does not contain the previously passed data** for attribute 'model'. And I'm using `onBeforeShow`, because the documentation explicitly states this is where you will find any data used in `toMaster()`.

```
onBeforeShow: function(event){
  // extract the model from the event data...
  if( typeof event.data.model !== "undefined") // because event.data.model is not defined, the model is never set :(
     this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(event.data.model));
},
```

From [SplitContainer.toMaster documentation, referring to parameter oData](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html#toMaster)

> {object}  oData Since version 1.7.1. This optional object can carry any payload data which should be made available to the target page. The "beforeShow" event on the target page will contain this data object as "data" property.

So where's it gone and how do I pass it? I'm basically trying to cascade the event data from the initial view, through a subsequent view, and then on to the final Master view (menu). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a small jsBin that shows how the event works: http://jsbin.com/zonovuzixi/3/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script>
    (function () {
      "use strict";
      var detailPage = new sap.m.Page({ 
        title: "firstDetail",
        content: new sap.m.Button({ 
          text: "to page 2",
          press: function () {
            splitApp.toDetail(secondDetailPage.getId(),"show",{foo :"bar"});
          }
        })
      });

      var secondDetailPage = new sap.m.Page({ title: "secondDetail"})
      .addEventDelegate({
        onBeforeShow: function(evt) {
          sap.m.MessageToast.show(evt.data.foo)
        }
      });


      var splitApp = new sap.m.SplitApp({
        detailPages: [detailPage, secondDetailPage]
      });

      splitApp.placeAt("content");
    })();
  </script>
  </head>

<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how your "nav","to" handler is implemented since it is something custom. Also, I don't know if you added the EventDelegate of `onBeforeShow` to the correct page.

Comment: Awesome Tobias, thanks! It was that the onBeforeShow delegate event is specific to the page, not the view. I made some changes to the JSBin and it works as I was expecting.